# Remove unknown text appearing on page

Tags: php, html

I have used a widget called addthisevent to allow users to add a class booking to their calendar. It is all working as indented but when I echo the link to the page I get a random ‘1’ next to the button. As you can see here -- http://oi60.tinypic.com/10fu8ac.jpg --

==add_event.php==

```
<?php

//Call session variables
$start_time = $_SESSION['class_time_start'];
$end_time = $_SESSION['class_time_end'];
$date = $_SESSION['class_date'];
$class_name = $_SESSION['class_name'];
$client_F_name = $_SESSION['firstname'];
$client_L_name = $_SESSION['lastname'];
$client_email = $_SESSION['email'];

//echo addthisevent script
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://addthisevent.com/libs/ate-latest.min.js"></script>';

//echo addthisevent with the variables in place, ready to be converted using the JS function
echo '<a href="http://example.com/link-to-your-event" title="Add to Calendar" class="  addthisevent" id="addthisevent">'
, 'Add to Calendar'
, '<span class="_start">' . $date . ' ' . $start_time . '</span>'
, '<span class="_end">' . $date . ' ' . $end_time . '</span>'
, '<span class="_zonecode">36</span>'
, '<span class="_summary">' . $class_name . ' Class</span>'
, '<span class="_description">Your ' . $class_name . ' class with ****</span>'
, '<span class="_location">*****</span>'
, '<span class="_organizer">*****</span>'
, '<span class="_organizer_email">******</span>'
, '<span class="_facebook_event">*****</span>'
, '<span class="_all_day_event">false</span>'
, '<span class="_date_format">YYYY/MM/DD</span>'
, '</a>';
?>
```

Let me know if you need more code as I understand this is a weird issue I'm having.

I really can't work out what is causing it. I know it is definitely coming from the php above. If there is a way to fix this issue or just to simply remove the '1' after the page has loaded as a workaround that would be great

Thanks

The page link is http://217.37.5.115/content/temppage.php

you will need to select the dropdown boxes for it to appear

In short:

I use this function below to run a php script when the value of one of the dropdown boxes changes

===temppage.php (main page)===

```
<script>
    function class_space_Update(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("class_spaces").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            //code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
            //code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("class_spaces").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    addthisevent.refresh();                                                
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "../includes/get/class_spaces.php?id=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }
    }
</script>
```

===class_spaces.php===

```
<?php
//Set session variables
//Session 'class_time_start'
$_SESSION['class_time_start'] = $start_time;

//Session 'class_time_end'
$_SESSION['class_time_end'] = $end_time;

//Session 'class_date'
$_SESSION['class_date'] = $date;

//Session 'space_left'
$_SESSION['space_left'] = $space_left;

//Include add_event.php
echo include_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/add_event.php");

//Close MySQLi connection
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

This isn't all of that file as it isn't really necessary.

If I comment out the echo include_once add_event.php part then the '1' does not appear.

Comment: could you provide a link to the broken page?

Comment: If you remove all the <span> tags does the '1' still appear?

Comment: yes the '1' still appears if I remove all the <span> tags

Comment: I've added a link to the page

Comment: so @Ben this 1 appears AFTER the A tag (including all spans), but you did't show us any phph code that is follow this A tag generation ;-)

Comment: don't you have print_r somewhere in that script, I can't see it but I've seen it left before and    echo print_r('test');    will output: test1

Comment: @Ben My first guess is that you're echoing the value of a test statement, but it could really be anything. If the code you posted the live code, as it appears on your server, or is there more after it?

Comment: @AoN I have just edited the post with more code if that helps

Comment: @AoN Yes that is the live code, however I did hide some info that is not relevant or is personal

Comment: @Ben check my answer, the solution I offer is to start output by `ob_start` so if your php generated something before this code it will be ignored, and terminate php execution right after echo by `exit()`. this solution is no good practice, but just to help you debug your application and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution I can offer for you is:

```
<?php

//Call session variables
$start_time = (isset($_SESSION['class_time_start']))?$_SESSION['class_time_start']:'';
$end_time = (isset($_SESSION['class_time_end']))?$_SESSION['class_time_end']:'';
$date = (isset($_SESSION['class_date']))?$_SESSION['class_date']:'';
$class_name = (isset($_SESSION['class_name']))?$_SESSION['class_name']:'';
$client_F_name = (isset($_SESSION['firstname']))?$_SESSION['firstname']:'';
$client_L_name = (isset($_SESSION['lastname']))?$_SESSION['lastname']:'';
$client_email = (isset($_SESSION['email']))?$_SESSION['email']:'';

//echo addthisevent script
ob_start();
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://addthisevent.com/libs/ate-latest.min.js"></script>';

//echo addthisevent with the variables in place, ready to be converted using the JS function
echo '<a href="http://example.com/link-to-your-event" title="Add to Calendar" class="  addthisevent" id="addthisevent">'
, 'Add to Calendar'
, '<span class="_start">' . $date . ' ' . $start_time . '</span>'
, '<span class="_end">' . $date . ' ' . $end_time . '</span>'
, '<span class="_zonecode">36</span>'
, '<span class="_summary">' . $class_name . ' Class</span>'
, '<span class="_description">Your ' . $class_name . ' class with ****</span>'
, '<span class="_location">*****</span>'
, '<span class="_organizer">*****</span>'
, '<span class="_organizer_email">******</span>'
, '<span class="_facebook_event">*****</span>'
, '<span class="_all_day_event">false</span>'
, '<span class="_date_format">YYYY/MM/DD</span>'
, '</a>';
exit();
```

Comment: Wow that actually worked. How did the ob_start() fix it? Thank you :D

Comment: there is two thing `ob_start` cleans everything php outputed before this script (including error messagies), and `exit()` prevent to output anything after :-) But as I said in comment - this solution is BAD practice. You should find the code that executes after this echo, or wrap somehow this script.

Comment: I have figured out what was causing the '1'. In the class_spaces.php file where I was including the add_event.php file,  I removed the echo and the '1' disappeared. Thanks for the help though :D